# PHP HTML Form - AJAX Changes not submitted

Tags: php, html, ajax, form-submit

I have a simple HTML Form that allows users to select a Type value. Based on the selected Type value they can then select from a list of Categories. The Categories are conditional based on the Type - when you select the Type a query is run against a database to select the matching Categories and display these as the select menu.

This is all working well as far as displaying the matching Categories, however when I submit the form the value for the selected Category is not part of the HTTP request and therefore nothing is being added to the database.

Here's the 2 fields in the HTML Form:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="type" class="control-label col-sm-3" >Type</label>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-8">
                <select class="form-control" name="type" id="type" onchange="getCategories(this.value)">
                    <option value=""></option>
                     <option value="Business">Business</option>
                     <option value="Commercial">Commercial</option>
                     <option value="Commercial Land">Commercial Land</option>
                     <option value="Land">Land</option>
                     <option value="Rental">Rental</option>
                     <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
                     <option value="Rural">Rural</option>
                     </select>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category" class="control-label col-sm-3" >Category</label>
            <div class="input-group col-xs-8" class="" id="categoryList">
                <select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
                    <option value=""></option>
                </select>
            </div>                  
    </div>
```

Here's the script that is called when the users makes a Type selection:

```
function getCategories(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("categoryList").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        }
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("categoryList").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
            var status = xmlhttp.status == 200 ? 'success' : 'error'
            var group = document.getElementById("categoryList")
            group.classList.add(status)
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "getPropertyCategories.php?type=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

This is working fine to show the conditional Category select menu based on the Type selection, but the Category selection isn't included as part of the form submission.

The getPropertyCategories.php returns the following for example:

```
<select class="form-control" name="category" id="category">
 <option></option>
 <option value='Accommodation/Tourism'>Accommodation/Tourism</option>
 <option value='Automotive' selected='selected' >Automotive</option>
 <option value='Beauty/Health'>Beauty/Health</option>
 <option value='Education/Training'>Education/Training</option><option value='Food/Hospitality'>Food/Hospitality</option>
 <option value='Franchise'>Franchise</option><option value='Home/Garden'>Home/Garden</option>
 <option value='Import/Export/Whole'>Import/Export/Whole</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: You aren't adding the `category`

Comment: And what exactly are you setting the innerHTML of #categoryList to?

Answer (score 0):

Change the id of the select menu to match the id specified in the javascript - or vice versa

```
            <select class="form-control" name="category" id="categoryList">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
```